# What error does "ExtAudioFileWriteAsync -50" indicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, core-audio

I'm attempting to write an AAC file from the output stream of an AUGraph, and on playback my file only plays a buzzing noise, and I get the error `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync -50`.

I'd like to know what it means so that I can search for and destroy the problem.

Thanks to any Core Audio ninjas that can hook a brother up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, the `-50 error` is a `kAudio_ParamError error`, defined in CoreAudioTypes.h.

Therefore, one of the parameters being passed to `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync` must be faulty.

Comment: Did you know what was your wrong parameter? I face the same error and have no clue at all...